# disable IE quirks Document mode via XSLT in Google Search Applaince

Tags: google-search-appliance

This question is targeted more to those who are familiar with customising the XSLT in the Google Search Appliance.

Where in the XSLT can i insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` so that it appears at the start of the HTML in the front-door and the results page ?

I have tried inserting it at the start of the XSLT and it does not appear at the start of the HTML in the GSA front door or the results page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I added the code (Snippet A) below

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML&gt;</xsl:text>
```

To Search within Results search input page (can be customized)

```
<!-- **********************************************************************
 "Search Within Results" search input page (can be customized)
     ********************************************************************** -->
<xsl:template name="swr_search">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML&gt;</xsl:text>
```

To modify the front door, I added the code below to "Front door" search input page (can be customized)

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML&gt;</xsl:text>
```

To modify the advanced search section, I added the same snippet above to the following section.

```
<!-- **********************************************************************
 Advanced search page (do not customize)
     ********************************************************************** -->
....
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML&gt;</xsl:text>
<html>
```

And added Snippet A to the code below in the XSLT.

```
<!-- **********************************************************************
 Search results (do not customize)
     ********************************************************************** -->
<xsl:template name="search_results">
<xsl:if test="$is_embedded_mode != '1'">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;html&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>

  <!-- *** HTML header and style *** -->
  <xsl:call-template name="langHeadStart"/>
```